# Universal module definition - writing style

Tags: javascript, amd, umd

It took me a long time to understand this pattern at first, and I think it is mostly because of the way that it is written:

```
(function(root, factory) {
    // Export MyModule depending on the environment
    if (typeof define === "function" && define.amd) {
        define("MyModule", [], factory);
    } else {
        root.MyModule = factory();
    }
}(this, function() {
    return { 
        // Module definition
    };
}));
```

Isn't that the exact same thing as this?

```
(function(root) {
    var factory = function() {
        return { 
            // Module definition
        };
    };
    // Export MyModule depending on the environment
    if (typeof define === "function" && define.amd) {
        define("MyModule", [], factory);
    } else {
        root.MyModule = factory();
    }
}(this));
```

There is a var statement now, but I find this much easier to read. Am I missing something here? Is there a good reason to use the first approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Isn't that the exact same thing as this?

Not *exactly* - those `root` and `factory` variables are now in the scope of the module definition, it is one closure level deeper. And this has the grave disadvantage that `factory` cannot (trivially) be garbage-collected any more, while in the first pattern it was really anonymous.

> I find this much easier to read

I disagree. AMD and UMD resolve around a single "define" wrapper that is called with a factory - where the contents of the factory function are the interesting ones (the "main" content of the file) and the definition call is nothing more but a header. This becomes especially obvious when the header is minified and takes only a single line.
In contrast, in the proposed alternative the module is hidden somewhere deep in that IEFE - it even needs to be indented one more level than normally.

Comment: Makes total sense, I didn't even think of that. Thank you!